# Clion IDE, Whenever i create new file gives error

Tags: cmake, clion

In CLion IDE, whenever I create a new project C++ the `main.cpp` works fine but when I made new C++ source file it gives me the error:

```
====================[ Build | cpp_files | Debug ]===============================
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2021.2.3\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build "D:\Application\Clion\cpp files\cmake-build-debug" --target cpp_files -- -j 6
[ 33%] Linking CXX executable cpp_files.exe
CMakeFiles\cpp_files.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main':
D:/Application/Clion/cpp files/main.cpp:3: multiple definition of `main'
CMakeFiles\cpp_files.dir/objects.a(khush.cpp.obj):D:/Application/Clion/cpp files/khush.cpp:3: first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [cpp_files.exe] Error 1

mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cpp_files.dir/all] Error 2

mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cpp_files.dir/rule] Error 2

mingw32-make.exe: *** [cpp_files] Error 2

CMakeFiles\cpp_files.dir\build.make:108: recipe for target 'cpp_files.exe' failed

CMakeFiles\Makefile2:81: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cpp_files.dir/all' failed

CMakeFiles\Makefile2:88: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cpp_files.dir/rule' failed

Makefile:123: recipe for target 'cpp_files' failed
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhUyC.png)

Comment: You need to have only **one definition** of `main` among all your source files. If `main.cpp` defines this function, then `khush.cpp` shouldn't define it. Or vice versa.

Comment: Note for the future, that error message should be included into the question post as **text**, not linked as image. Please, (re-)read [ask].